# Get value from multi tr of table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many table row, i want to get the value (it's a number) of each row to an array !

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="url">
<table id="temp1" class="table datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct1" class="product" name="pduct[]" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct2" class="product" name="pduct[]" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct3" class="product" name="pduct[]" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct4" class="product" name="pduct[]" /></td>
        </tr>                        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Like this code, i want to get the value of each "pduct" !

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: the `id` element should be unique. (You could still get the values into an array, but you should fix the `id`s in any case.)

Comment: @nnnnnn so how can i do that ? Please help

Comment: on what event do you want to get the value of the inputs.. use class instead of ID

Answer (score 1):

You can select the elements in question with `$('#temp1 input[name="pduct[]"]')` - that is, use the elements' `name` attribute, but limited to inputs that are within `#temp1`.

To get all their values you could use the [`.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/), which returns a new jQuery object, and then the [`.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to convert that to an array:

```
var arr = $('#temp1 input[name="pduct[]"]').map(function() { return this.value }).get()
```

In the context of, say, a button click, you'd have something like the following:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var arr = $('#temp1 input[name="pduct[]"]').map(function() { return this.value }).get()

  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Get Values</button>
<table id="temp1" class="table datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct" name="pduct[]" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct" name="pduct[]" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct" name="pduct[]" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct" name="pduct[]" /></td>
        </tr>                        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that the HTML in the original version of question was invalid because the `id` attribute needs to be unique. But that doesn't stop this code working because I'm selecting based on the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add class attribute in the input tag. (e.g. `class="abc"`)
2. Use Jquery.

   ```
   $('.abc').each(function(i, obj) {
       //$(this).val(); << return value
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery**

You can use [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to grab all the input values of a form.

In your example, you can do something like this:

```js
var formData = $('#form1').serializeArray();    \\Outputs in the form [{name, value}]
var formArray = formData.map(function(element){ \\If you only want the values
 return element.value;
})
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="url">
<table id="temp1" class="table datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct1" class="product" name="pduct[]" value="1"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct2" class="product" name="pduct[]"  value="2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct3" class="product" name="pduct[]"  value="3"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct4" class="product" name="pduct[]"  value="4"/></td>
        </tr>                        
    </tbody>
</table> 
</form>
```

**Native Javascript**

You can do the same in native javascript by instantiating a FormData object and using it's methods to grab all the input values.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("form1");
var formData = new FormData(form);
var formArray = [];
for(var value of formData.values()){
 formArray.push(value);
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="url">
<table id="temp1" class="table datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct1" class="product" name="pduct[]" value="1"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct2" class="product" name="pduct[]"  value="2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct3" class="product" name="pduct[]"  value="3"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="pduct4" class="product" name="pduct[]"  value="4"/></td>
        </tr>                        
    </tbody>
</table> 
</form>
```